# I am wanting to return to a previous funtion in Powershell, to rectify with user error if a variable is met?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

The current script is as follows;

```
$HN = hostname
$DN = Get-ADComputer -identity $HN -Properties DistinguishedName | select-object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName 

#*

$OU = 'OU=Workstations,DC=$domain,DC=$domain,DC=$domain'
[array]$A = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope OneLevel -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 
[array]$DropDownArray = $A | Sort-Object 
function Return-DropDown {
   if ($DropDown.SelectedItem -eq $B){
        $DropDown.SelectedItem = $DropDown.Items[0]
        $Form.Close()
    }
    else{
        $Form.Close()
    }
}
function SelectGroup{
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")


    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

    $Form.width = 600
    $Form.height = 200
    $Form.Text = ”DropDown”

    $DropDown = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $DropDown.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(140,10)
    $DropDown.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(300,80)

    ForEach ($Item in $DropDownArray) {
     [void] $DropDown.Items.Add($Item)
    }

    $Form.Controls.Add($DropDown)

    $DropDownLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $DropDownLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,10) 
    $DropDownLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40) 
    $DropDownLabel.Text = "Select Group:"
    $DropDown.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri",15,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
 
    $Button = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Button.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(140,50)
    $Button.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(150,50)
    $Button.Text = "Select an Item"
    $Button.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri",11,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $Button.Add_Click({Return-DropDown})
    $form.Controls.Add($Button)
    $form.ControlBox = $false

    $Button = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Button.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(290,50)
    $Button.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(150,50)
    $Button.Text = "Finish"
    $Button.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri",11,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $Button.Add_Click({Move-ADObject -Identity "$DN" -TargetPath "$OU" | Return-DropDown})
    $form.Controls.Add($Button)
    $form.ControlBox = $false

    $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
    [void] $Form.ShowDialog()

    $B = $dropdown.SelectedItem
    
    return $B
}
$B = SelectGroup
```

I would like to develop this tool and add as an aditional option to return to the begining of the previous function;

```
  $Button = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $Button.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(290,50)
    $Button.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(150,50)
    $Button.Text = "Back"
    $Button.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri",11,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $Button.Add_Click({Return to #* })
    $form.Controls.Add($Button)
    $form.ControlBox = $false
```

Not sure how to achieve this, hoping to find help on here.

I have looked at loops and breaks but nothing seems to fit or that i can adapt to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for simple repetition of the form function, you could do something like this (unless your tool hides the PowerShell window).

```
Do {
    # Move these lines from #*
    $OU = 'OU=Workstations,DC=$domain,DC=$domain,DC=$domain'
    [array]$A = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope 
OneLevel -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 
    [array]$DropDownArray = $A | Sort-Object 

    $B = SelectGroup 
    #{... Do Work on $B, if desired ...}
    $Stop = Read-Host -Prompt 'Do you want to stop?'
} Until ($Stop -match '(Y|y|Yes|YES|yes)')
```

Otherwise you'll need to alter your "return-dropdown" function to not close your form and implement your "back" button another way.